# What concrete type can accept an IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i have a method with a return type of `IEnumerable<T>`, and I need to capture the output of this method in a variable.  I cannot use var to declare the variable, because the variable has to be declared outside of my try/catch block.  So, what concrete Type can I use to declare my variable, that will accept the `IEnumerable<T>` output of my method?  Here's what this scenario looks like:

```
IEnumerable<string> CalleeMethod() {...}

IEnumerable<string> CallerMethod() 
{
   List<string> temp = null;
   try
   {
      temp = CalleeMethod();
   }
   catch(Exception exception)
   {
      Debug.WriteLine(exception.GetBaseException().Message);
   }
   return temp;
}
```

This example doesn't work because when I declare `temp` as `List<T>`, I get the error:  `cannot convert IEnumerable<T> to List<T>`.  I know I can call `.ToList()`, or cast the output of `CalleeMethod()` to `List<T>`, but I am wanting to simply define the `temp` variable with a concrete Type that can hold the `IEnumerable<T>` output of `CalleeMethod()` without having to cast it.  So, what concrete Type can I declare `temp` as that will not throw the `cannot convert...` error?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `IEnumerable<string> temp = null;` ?

Comment: Is there not a concrete type I can use?

Comment: @TylerJones of course... no. You have declared `IEnumerable<string> CalleeMethod` so the only type you can use is `IEnumerable` or it's parents, not children

Comment: "I need a concrete type, not an interface" comment makes this *very* unclear question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `IEnumerable<String>`?

Comment: There is no concrete type you have access to. Interfaces are types too, by the way.

Comment: @TylerJones You don't unless you've left out extremely relevant information out of your question. Based on what you asked, `IEnumerable<string>` is the correct answer. If you want something else, ask what you're really after.

Comment: @Joey so, there is no concrete type that can hold IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: @TylerJones Why do you think you need a concrete type? Your `CalleeMethod` method returns an `IEnumerable<string>` so nothing else would work. (other than `IEnumerable` or `object`, but then `return temp` would raise an error)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `IEnumerable<string> temp = Enumerable.Empty<String>();`

Comment: @TylerJones very confusing why this suggestion is any better/different than one by Chris Pitman (as this one creates extra unused objects)... Also if you have R# `var`<->concrete type conversions are half click away...

Answer (score 0):

@hvd is correct.  I think you have some concepts crossed. 'IEnumerable T' is different than 'IEnumerable string '.  This is a simple generic version...

```
public class GenericTest
{
    public IEnumerable<T> CalleeMethod<T>() where T : class
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void IEnumerableT()
{
    var x = new GenericTest();
    IEnumerable<string> result = x.CalleeMethod<string>();
}
```